# How to decrement the value of the declared variable in java after each execution

Tags: java, constants

```
public class test {
    public static void main() {
        i = 5;
        i--;
        System.out.println("The value of i is" + i);
    }
}
```

In the above program I want the value of constant `i` ,being reduced after every execution of the program but it doesn't happen and can't happen. Is there a way by which I can reduce the value of declared constant `i`?

Comment: Please make an effort on indentation.

Comment: how to do that in blue j environment?(java preference)?

Comment: For your question, save the value of your variable within a file and read it each time you're launching it.

Comment: What are you trying to solve here? Why do you need to do that?

Comment: Is your goal just to print the numbers 5 to -infinity? 

Is there a reason you want the program to be ran multiple  times to achieve this ?

Comment: See im creating a hotel booking program.So there are fixed number of rooms in each hotel so as the program is being executed more number of times the number of rooms decrease hence i want the constant value to decrease.(The constant value represents the number of rooms)

Comment: Generally constants are constants because their value does not change...what you want is most likely a variable and a loop to decrease the value of the variable on each iteration thenless you mean a single instance of your program as in your program reads a file, decreases the value and then saves that change to a file?

Answer (score 0):

You just cant do that....

use java preferences, you can store the value and read it again every time the application starts...

```
 void main(){
        i = getValueFromPreferences();
        i--;
        System.out.println("The value of i is"+i);
    }
```

## Example:

```
String key = "myCounter";
//method for writing
public void setPreference(final int newVal) {
    Preferences prefs = Preferences.userRoot().node(this.getClass().getName());
    prefs.putInt(key, newVal);
}

//method for reading back 
public int getValue(){
    Preferences prefs = Preferences.userRoot().node(this.getClass().getName());
    return prefs.getInt(key, -1);
}
```

Comment: how do i do it? in blue j environment

Comment: awesome ill try it out

Comment: i tried to know  how to setup prefrences but im just not understanding, the other guys are using different environments and using some android keyword for every line .

Answer (score 0):

You must store i outside of java.

1. In environment variable
2. In a file
3. In database
4. Get initial value as parameter and return i+1 as exit code for next execution

Answer (score 0):

```
Try this code:

public class Test {
    private static int i = 5;
    static void main() {
        i--;
        System.out.println("The value of i is" + i);
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
     Test test = new Test();
     test.main();
     test.main();
     test.main();
    }

}
```